# vscode.dev: An unexpected error occurred that requires a reload of this page

Tags: visual-studio-code

An unexpected error occurred that requires a reload of this page.
The workbench failed to connect to the server (Error: No remote extension installed to resolve tunnel.)

Open VS Code tunnel.

It was working perfectly fine. Is it an update or something on the side of vscode.dev?

Comment: same for me. Was working fine before today

Answer (score 0):

Now it is working fine.

If it is not related to the classic "intern messed up", VS Code should tell us in advance.

Comment: If you found a solution to your own question then please update the original question. Otherwise comments related to the question are better suited as a comment not an answer